# Implementing SlideView Animation SlideFromTop and SlideFromBottom

Tags: ios

I am implementing SlideView animation which will slide from top or bottom depending on the configuration.

For the slideFromTop it works perfectly fine. For slideFromBottom it only shows half of the slide view. Here is my SlideViewController.

```
const int VIEW_HEIGHT = 44; 

-(void) slideInFromBottom 
{
    CGRect screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,screenSize.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, VIEW_HEIGHT);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{

        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, screenSize.size.height - VIEW_HEIGHT, self.view.frame.size.width,VIEW_HEIGHT);

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 delay:2.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent animations:^{

            self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, screenSize.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, VIEW_HEIGHT); 

        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        }];


    }];

}

-(void) slideInFromTop
{
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, (-1) * VIEW_HEIGHT, self.view.frame.size.width, VIEW_HEIGHT);

    CGRect temp = self.view.frame;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{

        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,VIEW_HEIGHT);

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 delay:2.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent animations:^{

            self.view.frame = temp;

        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        }];


    }];

}
```

The user calls the SlideViewController using the following code:

```
-(IBAction) save:(id) sender 
{
    SlideViewController *slideViewController = [[SlideViewController alloc] initWithTitle:@"Customer has been saved!" animationType:SlideInFromTop];
    [self.view addSubview:slideViewController.view];
}
```

UPDATE 2:

```
 self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, screenSize.size.height - (1.3 * VIEW_HEIGHT), self.view.frame.size.width,VIEW_HEIGHT);
```

Comment: If it only shows half of the view, doesnt that imply that you need to multiply the y factor by 2?

Comment: Actually it seems like more than half is being displayed but my question is why does is NOT display the whole thing just like the slideFromTop animation. Update 2 shows the slideFromBottom changes which shows the whole view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save yourself some trouble and just download and install [FTUtils](http://ftutils.com/docs/setup)

Just drop the project into yours, include the header, then you can do the animation in one line:

```
[myVu slideInFrom:kFTAnimationTop duration:0.75f delegate:self];
```

It has over a dozen very useful animations like the "pop in" effect on UIAlertViews. I litteraly use it all the time.

Comment: I downloaded FTUtils but I am having trouble in setting it up. Can you look at my post here => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8730076/adding-ftutils-to-an-ios-project

Answer (score 1):

I created a library for this called [MFSlidingView](https://github.com/mikefrederick/MFSlidingView) that some people might find useful.