# Adding FTUtils to an iOS Project

Tags: ios

I am trying to add FTUtils to my iOS project but even though I have added the "FTUtils.xcodeproj" project to my own custom project I am not able to make a reference to the

```
#import <FTUtils/FTAnimation.h>
```

I followed the setup from this link: http://ftutils.com/docs/setup

When I drag the FTUtils.xcodeproj into my own project it does not ask me anything. Also the documentation says that check mark the libFTUtils.a. What checkbox are they talking about?

Answer (score 1):

This answer is a little bit late, but, the only thing that you have to do is to drag this files to your project :

- FTUtils.h
- FTAnimation.h
- FTUtils+NSObject.h
- FTAnimationManager.h
- FTAnimation+UIView.h
- FTUtils+UIGestureRecognizer.h

In Build Phases tag ---> Link Binary with libraries add:

- libFTUtils-fat.a

Then you have to import to your class:

- #import "FTAnimation.h"
- #import "FTAnimation+UIView.h"

And use it like (with the effect/Animation you want to use, of course):

```
[self.view slideOutTo:kFTAnimationLeft inView:self.view duration:1.0 delegate:nil startSelector:nil stopSelector:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

I just  dragged the .m and .h files into my project. I prefer to have the source instead of the library so I can edit it. I have added a number of my own animations to it.

But if you prefer to use the static library, I believe you open FTUtils.xcodeproj, build it then drag the .a file it will build and .h files into your project.

Comment: On the website they say to copy three .h and .m files which includes FTUtils.h, FTAnimationManager.h and FTAnimationManager.m. I copied these three files but then I was not able to use any slide methods. Do I have to copy all the .h and .m files in order for this to work?

Comment: In addition, I think you at least need FTAnimation+UIView .h and .m. That is the actual category implementation.