# Elegant view transition animation?

Tags: iphone, animation, uiview, transition

I have a view that looks like this:

[image]

And I display a pop up window like this:

[image]

Every transition I try looks like a cheap hack. Apple has a similar white pop up window in their app store that sort of bounces open like an alert view then the background fades a little bit.

How can I achieve this effect?

Right now I just blur it in like this:

```
[previewView setAlpha:0.0];
    [[self.view.window.subviews objectAtIndex:0] addSubview:previewView];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [previewView setAlpha:1.0];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

and it looks terrible.

I don't really care what the animation is. I just want it to look professional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718494/implementing-slideview-animation-slidefromtop-and-slidefrombottom/8722691#8722691).

FTUtils has a pop-in animation that does exactly as you describe.

You use it with a single line too:

```
[myView popIn:0.35f delegate:self];
```

Or pop out:

```
[myView popOut:0.35f delegate:self];
```