# Displaying multiple markers/dots and bottom drawer like new Google Maps for iOS

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, modalviewcontroller, slidingdrawer, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am using Google maps SDK for iOS. My question is two parts:

1) I have multiple markers on my map. But I want them displayed as dot and when tapped a marker needs to be place. Like the default behavior of Google maps iOS[image]

2) How do I bring a sliding drawer on the bottom when tapped on the marker? I understand the I must use `didMarkerTapped` by delegating 'GMSMapViewDelegate' but are there any libraries for sliding views from the bottom?[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below approach:

1, Initially add all the markers with an icon image same as the small dot you require. Then when a marker is tapped, in `didTapMarker` you can add a new marker at the tapped position with an icon set to the default marker icon you have shown. Keep the refernce to this marker so that you can remove it when user taps on the map again.

2, For implementing a sliding menu from the bottom, you can try using [FTUtils](http://ftutils.com/docs/setup) . Please find an [earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718494/implementing-slideview-animation-slidefromtop-and-slidefrombottom) on the same